# How can i solve the error of vuex is not defined with the laravel

Tags: vue.js

hello everyone i am using laravel mix to create my vue js app recently. It compiles correctly with no errors. But on the browser console, it says:Vuex is not defined.

Heres is the code. The guide i am using wrote it exactly that way with no mistakes. so i dont really know where the error is coming from. Heres the code:

```
import Vue from "vuex";
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';
import * as actions from './actions';
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vuex.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.store({
    modules:{

    },
    state:{

    },
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
})
```

Comment: You import it as `Vue` at `import Vue from "vuex";`. Change that to `import Vuex from "vuex";`.

Comment: ive done that but now the error changed from the previous one to this saying:  vuex__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.store is not a constructor

Comment: also saying: vuex__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.use is not a function

Comment: I don't think `vuex.store()` is a function, instead, it is `vuex.createStore()`. And `.use()` is not on `vuex`, but on `vue`.

Comment: its saying createStore() is not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing what `Vue` is and what `Vuex` is.

Try something like the following:

```js
import Vuex from "vuex";

import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';
import * as actions from './actions';

export const store = new Vuex.createStore({
    modules:{

    },
    state:{

    },
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
});
```

and wherever you do `createApp()` with `Vue`,

```js
import { store } from 'path/to/storefile.js';

...
const app = createApp(...)

app.use(store);
```

Comment: still saying .createstore() is not a function

Comment: @Dever What is the VueX version you are using. Syntaxes between version are not the same

Comment: version 3.6.2 thats the version